# Where is the redmine config file/database configuration?

Tags: ubuntu, redmine

I can't seem to find the redmine config file or better said the database config on ubuntu.
I want to make a dump of my redmine db.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Redmine from source (such as an source archive, or a git or subversion checkout), you can find the database credentials in the `config/database.yml` file within the directory you have installed Redmine to.

If you have installed Redmine using the Ubuntu `redmine` package, this file can be found in `/etc/redmine/${instance}/database.yml` (with `${instance}` being the name of your Redmine instance). If you have just one instance configured, this  is likely `/etc/redmine/default/database.yml`.

For more details about changes of the `redmine` package from a vanilla upstream Redmine, please refer to https://wiki.debian.org/Redmine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your Answer but i can't find it on there (the bad thing is that i didn't install it), even with grep and aux commands i wasn't able to find it. Do you have any more tips for me? Would really appreciate it :)

Comment: I don't even have redmine in the etc folder.

Comment: In that case, the original operator likely installed Redmine from source. You could check the web server confioguration or the process list for hints. Or ask the original operator or their colleagues....

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but this could help future users.

I couldn't find my config, and I didn't remember how I installed the app. I could find it using `locate 'redmine'` in /opt/redmine/redmine.

It seems that one will find it there if he has followed [the official install guide for debian](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Debian_9)